# `nomencl`: error "Undefined control sequence. <argument> \list@fname"

Tags: errors, nomenclature, undefined, nomencl

I am writing a large document with a nomenclature using `nomencl`. Some `\nomenclature{foo}{bar}` entries cause the following error:

```
Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \list@fname
```

I am trying to find out how to fix the problem, and what in `foo` and `bar` (if anything) is causing the problem.

Manually removing the corresponding line from the `main.nls` file causes the error to disappear. But changing the contents of the line (derived from `foo` and `bar`) does not make the error disappear.

All of this seems to indicate that the error does not depend on `foo` and `bar`, but how is that possible?

I am not sure how to produce a small example that reproduces the error; any advice for how to do this would also be very much appreciated.

EDIT: following David Carlisle's advice, I have produced the following MWE:

`main.tex`

```
\documentclass{memo-l}
\usepackage[refpage]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

`main.nls`

```
\begin{thenomenclature} 
\nomgroup{Symbols}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
%  \item [foo] \begingroup bar \nomeqref{0.0}\nompageref{1}
  %this last line yields "! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \list@fname"
\end{thenomenclature}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: do you have a page break in the nomenclature list?

Comment: Yes, I do have a page break in the nomenclature list. Is that a problem? It would explain why the contents of foo and bar don't matter...

Comment: I thought you would have looking at the code:-)

Comment: looking at the code this command is used for putting NOMECLATURE in the page head but somewhat bravely using local definitions so I guess the page and enviroment scopes get out of sync but I don't know the package and couldn't make it fail with  quick test. You should be able to add an example probably you just need `\printnomenclature` and some setup copied from your real doc and hand write a `.nls` file with enough lines to show problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `nomencl` package by default loads `tocbasic` which is incompatible with `memo-l` (based on `amsbook`); this is the cause of the error you get. You need the option `notocbasic`.

Second, `\chapter*`, which is done by `\printnomencl`, sets by itself the headers, so we have to disable `\@mkboth` issued by `nomencl`.

Third, in order to get proper conversion to uppercase in the header, it's best to load `textcase` so `amsbook` will not use the primitive `\uppercase`, but the LaTeX-aware `\MakeUppercase`.

```
\documentclass{memo-l}
\usepackage[refpage,notocbasic]{nomencl}
\usepackage{textcase} % avoid amsbook using \uppercase
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\makenomenclature

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\thenomenclature}{\@mkboth}{\@gobbletwo}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{No number}

\lipsum[1-12]

\chapter{test}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_replicate:nn { 40 } { \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{AAAAA} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\lipsum[1-12]

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_step_inline:nn { 100 } { \nomenclature{#1}{--#1--} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

[image]